# How to implement ipv6 in python?

Tags: sockets

I want to connect my program with ipv6 and not ipv4
My code is:

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 128
PORT = someport
#SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
SERVER = 'someip'
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECTED_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECTED"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
```

I already know how to do it with ipv4, but not with ipv6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a very simple solution to that
You could add:

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET**6**, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

and then put the ipv6 on your server variable

Comment: Ohhh thank you. This was then fairly easy!

Comment: Yes it was! There are a lot of cool tutorials on Youtube showing all that cool stuff. Here is the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html